# Android ActioBar Style

Tags: android

What styles are available for ActionBar? ( OR I will have to define it) The one I am using the defautlt one (a line below all the tabs) Can I change color of that line?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the native ActionBar in Android 3.0+ (Honeycomb, tablets only), or are you using a library like [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) or [Android-ActionBar](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar)? In at least the first two cases, [this post from the official Android Developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) should help you out.

Comment: Android ActionBar in Honeycomb

Comment: From that blog, I can not use "<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBarView_TabView">"

Comment: Make sure you indicate you want to use that style in your overall theme; see under the header "Bringing it all together" on that page.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I followed that. It doesn't compile. XML file error is "error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBarView_TabView'."

Comment: Is your API level set to 11 or above in your manifest? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html And in your Eclipse project properties as well?